# Make nested SQL queries

Tags: sql

I want to do a Nested query to add the same data but with different filters.
I have tried something like this but that gives nothing or doesn't execute:

```
Select ENFACT.NUMFACT, CLIENT.NOM ,ENFACT.MONTMONTTC ,ECHEANC.DATEECHÉANCE AS DATE1, (Select ECHEANC.DATEECHÉANCE From ECHEANC ) AS DATE2 
From CLIENT, ENFACT, ECHEANC 
Where ENFACT.COCLI=CLIENT.COCLI 
And ENFACT.NUMFACT=ECHEANC.NUMFACT 
And ENFACT.TYPEFAC='F'
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You need a correlated subquery (i.e. includes a condition referencing the outer query.) However, I'd consider a LEFT JOIN instead of the subquery.

Comment: Have you looked into...`JOIN`s?

Comment: Can you describe better, and not use "same data but with different filters" (unclear what "some data" means, and "different filters" ?) Also: " give nothing or don't execute" but no error messages included, and it's unclear if the provided code 1) produces results 2) produces an error 3) what the desired output of this code should be.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
Select ENFACT.NUMFACT, CLIENT.NOM ,ENFACT.MONTMONTTC ,ECHEANC.DATEECHÉANCE AS DATE1, ECHEANC.DATEECHÉANCE AS DATE2 
From CLIENT inner join ENFACT 
on ENFACT.COCLI=CLIENT.COCLI 
inner join  ECHEANC
on ENFACT.NUMFACT=ECHEANC.NUMFACT 
where ENFACT.TYPEFAC='F'
```

You don't need a subquery, just a join between 3 tables. Up to you to choose between left or inner join, I used inner join in my example

Comment: Yes but in your query 'DATE1' and 'DATE2' have same constraints.
I want filter from today date and separe by part of different periods 
But Thank's you for inner join :)